# Particles not going down - Z Axis problem offset

Tags: 3d-view, particles, physics

I am trying to solve a particle direction problem, don´t know what I did but its not going down, I saved it and the next day this happened:

it's not going down in the Z axis, it was looking like the first image:

[image]

Is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a wind force too strong.